Make scenario connect to multiple Monday boards
Is there a way for a multiple boards in my monday.com to access one make.com scenario? So there's a webhook right, but that will only make the scenario listen to 1 board. How do i make it multiple? I am imagining that, maybe there's a way and somehow the webhook will just receive board ID and thats what will be used.
